How can I repair deteriorated wall plaster?
My wall has been deteriorating like this for over a year and I finally have the means to fix it. What is it and how can I fix it?


Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You shouldn't rely solely on a photo hosted elsewhere to explain your problem. Also, cost questions are prohibited. Please revise to explain your problem, ask a clear, specific question in your title, and embed the images rather than linking them.

Also, search before you post. After I fixed up your post I see that it's very similar to many others which already have answers on them. Judging by the wall and ceiling you have a leak in your roof or wall exterior.

welcome and thanks for posting +1

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: How to repair crumbling drywall or plaster?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Based on my personal experience in remodeling, you cannot just 'repair' damaged plaster. If not directly affected, you may be able to keep the plaster areas that are still holding up, but I'd remove all the damaged plaster. Once you remove it, you can trace and locate the source of the leak, fix the problem, then plaster anew. Good luck!
